# Open existing file of unknown extension

Tags: python, file-io

I need to open a file for reading, I know the folder it is in, I know it exists and I know the (unique) name of it but I don't know the *extension* before hand.

How can I open the file for reading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `glob` to find it:

```
import os
import glob

filename = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, name + '.*'))[0]
```

Or with a generator:

```
filename = next(glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder, name + '.*')))
```

Comment: Assuming there's only one file, `iglob` is probably going to be slower, not faster. (And if that assumption isn't true, the problem is ambiguous in the first place…)

Comment: @abarnert: `glob.glob()` just calls `list(glob.iglob())`, so I don't think pulling only the first result will be slower. I'll just get rid of the comment on the speed differences, as they will be negligible in either case.

Comment: OK, that's how recent versions of CPython implement it (including all 2.7 and 3.3). But check out early CPython 2.5 versions, or any Jython. At any rate, using `iglob` is unlikely to benefit speed significantly in any case where the problem is meaningful. And meanwhile, you've edited your answer to take out the speed claim anyway, so the point is pretty much moot.